# How to insert php post name into a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a post value named `$_POST['John']` and I want to insert the post name "John" into a variable but not its value.  How can I achieve this? Code Sample:

```
$_POST['John'] = "value";
```

Comment: something like this?

`foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
     var_dump($key); // john
    var_dump($value); // value
}`

Comment: Is there a special reason you have a post value and you don't know its key? It should be much more proper to have somthing like `$_POST['name'] = "John";` along with `$_POST['value'] = "value";` -> you should fix this first probably

Comment: @Kaddath I'm writing a function in php and needs the name of the $_POST to work properly.

Comment: `$_POST` variables come from the outside, usually from an HTML form that submits to your script. For security reasons, you should know where they come from, and their keys too. Even knowing that, checks are usually made on them because they can come from anywhere (it's easy to submit values you want to your script when you know its URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) is `PHP` function which is returning the keys from an array, you have only single `array` than we can use `0` as the key. if you have more than one `array` element you can use loop.

You can use `array_keys` as you mentioned there is one parameter use

```
$a = array_keys($_POST)[0];
```

https://3v4l.org/NUkkL

Comment: Thanks, I'm just a novice so I don't understand most of the code. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @AndyBrooke I HIGHLY recommend reading the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/) and using it [as a reference guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/funcref.php).

Comment: So many things that can go wrong using this answer.. the OP should fix the form instead, what a wrong world for this to get instant upvotes..

Comment: @Kaddath  the solution is about what he is asking, no where he mentioned about the form

Comment: You really see no problem in a question where a beginner asks for a post var without knowing its key? You don't realize how unsecure a code you give the OP when you don't know what he will do after? Anyway, not complaning about the answer, we see those everyday, but about the votes..

Comment: @Kaddath what do you mean? Can you clarify what you mean by the form?